# Why does destructor hang?

Tags: multithreading, delphi

I am trying to come up with a database worker thread that always has the same ID and can be used for all commands (for a given database) for the life of the app. The following class does this. But when I call Free on the class the the destructor enters an infinite loop. MsgWaitForMultipleObjects always return 2, never 0. After a lot of reading I still don't understand why. Can someone point out what I'm doing wrong? Thanks

```
unit BaseDBThread;

interface

uses
    Aurelius.Engine.ObjectManager,
    Constants,
    System.Classes,
    System.Rtti,
    System.SyncObjs,
    System.SysUtils;

type
  TBaseDBThread = class(TThread)
  protected
    fDBResult: TValue;
    fJobDone: TLightweightEvent;
    fJobProc: TProc;
    fJobReady: TLightweightEvent;
    fParamObj1: TObject;
    procedure DoSave;
    procedure Execute; override;
    function GetObjectManager: TObjectManager; virtual; abstract;
    procedure TerminatedSet; override;
    property DBResult: TValue read fDBResult write fDBResult;
    property ParamObj1: TObject read fParamObj1 write fParamObj1;
  public
    constructor Create(CreateSuspended: Boolean);
    destructor Destroy; override;
    function Save(aObj: TObject): Boolean;
    property ObjectManager: TObjectManager read GetObjectManager;
  end;

implementation

uses
    FVAurelius,
    System.TypInfo;

constructor TBaseDBThread.Create(CreateSuspended: Boolean);
begin
    inherited Create(CreateSuspended);

    fJobReady := TLightweightEvent.Create;
    fJobDone := TLightweightEvent.Create;
end;

destructor TBaseDBThread.Destroy;
begin
    fJobReady.Free;
    fJobDone.Free;

    if Assigned(fParamObj1) then
        fParamObj1.Free;

    inherited;
end;

procedure TBaseDBThread.DoSave;
var
    lId: string;
begin
    lId := GetStrProp(ParamObj1, STRID);
    if lId <> STRZeroLengthString then
    begin
        ObjectManager.Flush;
        DBResult := False;
    end
    else
    begin
        ObjectManager.Save(ParamObj1);
        DBResult := True;
    end;

    fJobDone.SetEvent;
end;

procedure TBaseDBThread.Execute;
begin
    while  fJobReady.WaitFor(INFINITE) = wrSignaled do
    begin
        fJobReady.ResetEvent;

        if not Terminated then
            fJobProc;
    end;
end;

function TBaseDBThread.Save(aObj: TObject): Boolean;
begin
    ParamObj1 := aObj;
    fJobProc := DoSave;
    fJobReady.SetEvent;//JobReady allows

    if fJobDone.WaitFor(INFINITE) = wrSignaled then
    begin
        fJobDone.ResetEvent;

        result := DBResult.AsBoolean;
    end;
end;

procedure TBaseDBThread.TerminatedSet;
begin
    fJobReady.SetEvent;

    inherited;
end;

end.
```

**UPDATE**

Here is a minimal project that demonstrates the situation. A key point that was not apparent in my original post is that I create the worker thread passing False for CreateSuspended. So the thread starts out being blocked by JobReady. It's in this same state when I try to exit the app. I think this is causing the hang on exit.

I thought I should set JobReady in the thread's destructor. But doing so generates an 'Object lock not owned' error. I couldn't figure out how to clear this error. I think that is my problem.

Unit4

```
unit Unit4;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.UITypes, System.Classes, System.Variants,
  FMX.Types, FMX.Controls, FMX.Forms, FMX.Graphics, FMX.Dialogs, Unit5;

type
  TForm4 = class(TForm)
  private
      fThing: TBaseDBThread;
    { Private declarations }
  public
      constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
      destructor Destroy; override;
      property Thing: TBaseDBThread read fThing write fThing;
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form4: TForm4;

implementation

{$R *.fmx}

constructor TForm4.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
    inherited;

    fThing := TBaseDBThread.Create(False);
end;

destructor TForm4.Destroy;
begin
    fThing.Free;

    inherited;
end;

end.
```

Unit5

```
unit Unit5;

interface

uses
//    Aurelius.Engine.ObjectManager,
//    Constants,
    System.Classes,
    System.Rtti,
    System.SyncObjs,
    System.SysUtils;

type
  TBaseDBThread = class(TThread)
  protected
    fDBResult: TValue;
    fJobDone: TLightweightEvent;
    fJobProc: TProc;
    fJobReady: TLightweightEvent;
    fParamObj1: TObject;
    procedure DoSave;
    procedure Execute; override;
//    function GetObjectManager: TObjectManager; virtual; abstract;
    procedure TerminatedSet; override;
    property DBResult: TValue read fDBResult write fDBResult;
    property ParamObj1: TObject read fParamObj1 write fParamObj1;
  public
    constructor Create(CreateSuspended: Boolean);
    destructor Destroy; override;
    function Save(aObj: TObject): Boolean;
//    property ObjectManager: TObjectManager read GetObjectManager;
  end;

implementation

uses
//    FVAurelius,
    System.TypInfo;

constructor TBaseDBThread.Create(CreateSuspended: Boolean);
begin
    inherited Create(CreateSuspended);

    fJobReady := TLightweightEvent.Create;
    fJobDone := TLightweightEvent.Create;
end;

destructor TBaseDBThread.Destroy;
begin
//    fJobReady.SetEvent;//Comment this in to see the error
    fJobReady.Free;
    fJobDone.Free;

    if Assigned(fParamObj1) then
        fParamObj1.Free;

    inherited;
end;

procedure TBaseDBThread.DoSave;
var
    lId: string;
begin
    lId := GetStrProp(ParamObj1, 'ID');
    if lId <> '' then
    begin
//        ObjectManager.Flush;
        DBResult := False;
    end
    else
    begin
//        ObjectManager.Save(ParamObj1);
        DBResult := True;
    end;

    fJobDone.SetEvent;
end;

procedure TBaseDBThread.Execute;
begin
    while  fJobReady.WaitFor(INFINITE) = wrSignaled do
    begin
        fJobReady.ResetEvent;

        if not Terminated then
            fJobProc;
    end;
end;

function TBaseDBThread.Save(aObj: TObject): Boolean;
begin
    ParamObj1 := aObj;
    fJobProc := DoSave;
    fJobReady.SetEvent;//JobReady allows

    if fJobDone.WaitFor(INFINITE) = wrSignaled then
    begin
        fJobDone.ResetEvent;

        result := DBResult.AsBoolean;
    end;
end;

procedure TBaseDBThread.TerminatedSet;
begin
    fJobReady.SetEvent;

    inherited;
end;

end.
```

**UPDATE 2**

Console Application

```
program Project5;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
    System.Classes,
    System.Rtti,
    System.SyncObjs,
    System.SysUtils;

type
  TBaseDBThread = class(TThread)
  public
    fJobReady: TLightweightEvent;
    procedure Execute; override;
    constructor Create(CreateSuspended: Boolean);
    destructor Destroy; override;
  end;

constructor TBaseDBThread.Create(CreateSuspended: Boolean);
begin
    inherited Create(CreateSuspended);

    fJobReady := TLightweightEvent.Create;
end;

destructor TBaseDBThread.Destroy;
begin
//    fJobReady.SetEvent;//Comment this in to see error
    fJobReady.Free;

    inherited;
end;

procedure TBaseDBThread.Execute;
begin
    while fJobReady.WaitFor(INFINITE) = wrSignaled do
    begin
        fJobReady.ResetEvent;
    end;
end;

var
    aThread: TBaseDBThread;

begin
  try
    aThread := TBaseDBThread.Create(False);//Change parameter to True for a clean exit
    WriteLn('Press enter to exit...');
    ReadLn;
    aThread.Free;
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
end.
```

Comment: I don't see any MsgWaitForMultipleObjects in your code. Where it is. What is it waiting for?

Comment: In your constructor, you should create the events before calling the inherited constructor.

Comment: @fpiette "In your constructor, you should create the events before calling the inherited constructor." Wrong. That was true in Delphi 5. In Delphi 6 `TThread` was changed so that that the OS thread is not created until `AfterConstruction`. In fact its why `AfterConstruction` was introduced. The constructor here is fine.

Comment: The destructor should not destroy the events before the thread is stopped.

Comment: @fpiette MsgWaitForMultipleObjects is called in the inherited destructor.

Comment: `if Assigned(foo) then foo.Free` is a little pointless because `foo.Free` includes a `nil` check. But that's not your problem. You say that the code hangs. Use the debugger to find out which line of code hangs. If you want us to help more, provide [mcve].

Comment: Thank you for your comments. They suggest the problem is not in this code but elsewhere. I thought I might have been misusing the event objects. I will isolate this code in a new project and see what happens.

Comment: @fpiette You say that `MsgWaitForMultipleObjects` is called in the inherited destructor. If that is the case you need to make sure that inherited destructor is called before you destroy the events your `MsgWaitForMultipleObjects` code is waiting fore otherwise your `MsgWaitForMultipleObjects` is waiting for nonexistent events and thus hangs.

Comment: @DavidU It is best NOT to rely on the inherited `TThread` destructor terminating the worker thread for you.  Do that yourself BEFORE you destroy your `TBaseDBThread` object.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan please see the update. Thanks.

Comment: Still doesnt look minimal. Why can't we have just a simple console program?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Update 2 contains a console program. Thanks.

Comment: The problem goes away if I use TSimpleEvent instead of TLightweightEvent. Thanks @DavidHeffernan.